# Existe (ou deveríamos criar) alguma convenção de quando utilizar a tag .NET?

Tags: debate, tags, tag-específica

Estive editando algumas perguntas com a tag [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) e acabei adicionando a tag [.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) em algumas.

Acabei parando pra pensar no motivo de estar colocando a tag [.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), pois isso é algo que deveria estar implícito. Digo, C# pertence à .NET.

Vocês pensam sempre antes de adicionar a tag [.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) em perguntas relacionadas a C#? Existe algum critério/convenção/regra que define quando deveríamos usar essa tag? Ou, caso não exista nada, devemos criar tal convenção?

<sub>Citei apenas a tag [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) na pergunta, mas isso vale também para as outras linguagens da plataforma, como [vb.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) e [f#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23).</sub>

Comment: "C# pertence à .NET", não necessariamente, C# pode ser relativo a .NET ou a Mono.

Comment: Não tinha pensado nisso, mas então deveríamos colocar em todas as perguntas a sobre C# a tag .NET?

Comment: Na minha opinião deveríamos assumir que o caso geral e C#/.NET e não colocar a tag .NET. Caso seja C#/mono, ai adicionava-se a tag mono. Por outro lado ha a questao de falar de querer falar na especificação do C# sem se prender a uma das plataformas, o que torna o meu argumento anterior invalido.

Comment: Acho desnecessário especificar que é ou não .NET. Deixaria a tag .NET somente pra casos mais específicos, tipo "Que mudanças teve em xpto library do .NET 4.5 pro .NET 5?"
Daqui a pouco aparece outra opção de C# que não seja VS+.NET ou Mono ou Unity ou Xamarin e aí só iria embolar tudo.